# Problem while using objcopy with "thin archive" file

Tags: gcc, objcopy

Please use following shell commands to reproduce the problem:

```
# create subdirectory
mkdir subdir

# create source files with dummy functions
echo 'void func1(){}' > file1.c
echo 'void func2(){}' > ./subdir/file2.c

# compiling sources into object files
gcc -c file1.c -o file1.o
gcc -c ./subdir/file2.c -o ./subdir/file2.o

# creating "thin archive" file from object files
ar crT out.a file1.o ./subdir/file2.o

# running objcopy, which leads to an error
objcopy out.a out_copy.a
```

As a result, following error occurs:

> objcopy:st0AENRL/subdir/file2.o: No such file or directory

P.S. Problem with objcopy occurs when "thin" archive is composed of object files from subdirectories.

Does anybody know if such objcopy's behavior is ok?

Comment: Probably it is a bug.
I've made a report on it on bugzilla:
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a bug.
It was reported [here](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24281).
Support of thin archives was temporary [disabled](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;h=f5f20315116c43110c058ec9d787e20f901309f2).